# Forest: Global settings for far out children

Tags: forest

I want smaller font size for all levels except the far out children (in the example below, everything except **I saw Jane.**) How do I do that with the `forestset`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics, edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    [S
        [subject
            [pronoun [I]]
        ]
        [predicate,before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}
            [verb [saw]]
        ] [object
            [noun
                [Jane.]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    \end{forest}  
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the code `for tree={font=\tiny}` effects the entire tree font whereas the code `where n children=0{font=\normalsize}{}` effects only the last level since the children are =0, from page 7 of the documentation -- http://ctan.imsc.res.in/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf

Comment: is there something else i can help you with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of the `forestset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics, edges]{forest}
\forestset{  % <---
  my tree/.style={for tree={forked edge,
                  where n children=0{font=\large} % <---
                                    {font=\small} % <---
                           }
                 }
          }% end of forestset

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{forest} my tree % <---
[S
    [subject
        [pronoun 
            [I]
        ]
    ]
    [predicate,before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}
        [verb 
            [saw]
        ]
    ] 
    [object
        [noun
            [Jane.]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics, edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{forest}for tree={font=\tiny},where n children=0{font=\normalsize}{},
    forked edges,
    [S
        [subject
            [pronoun [I]]
        ]
        [predicate,before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}
            [verb [saw]]
        ] [object
            [noun
                [Jane.]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    \end{forest}  
\end{center}
\end{document}
```